# MOTIF programming and X11 client?

Tags: linux, unix, x11, motif

iam interesting in MOTIF programming.

One question :

Is it right that in Motif GUI programming the actions are automaticly transformed and networked to other clients over the internet without network programming necessary ?

Are the commands automatic transformed by the X11 system and protocoll ?

WBR
Zabo

Comment: Can of worms.  You won't need to worry about network programming.  Yes, it does use the X11 display protocol for communication.  Depending on what you do, you might even do some Xlib programming also but even then you won't have to worry about network programming.  Are you sure about Motif?  There's no more market.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Yes i am shure. On UNIX/Linux System.

Comment: X11 is a network protocol. Motif has no significant network-related abilities of its own. It is not clear what exactly you mean by "commands" or "actions".

Answer (score 0):

In sort: Yes.

Motif (on UNIX) is implemented on top of XWindows.

Since XWindows allows for a networked interface, it's possible to run the application on a server, but have the user-interface appear on a remote workstation.  Obviously the mouse and keyboard of the workstation are used to operate the GUI.

That said, other XWindows user interface libraries are available for this use, and are much *much* more modern.  Gtk and Qt for example